# MySQL's net_read_timeout variable is reset to the intial value after a timeout during query

Tags: mysql

**Background**

I use the following code to import a SQL file into a MySQL database which worked for the `A.sql` file with a size of 23.4 MB:

```
mysql myDataBase < A.sql
```

Then, I have a second file, `B.sql` which is 11.7 MB. When I use the same code in the terminal, I get this error message:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 41: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

**Research and actions taken to solve the problem**

I did my research, and the following MySQL's webpage suggests that I have to increase the value of net_read_timeout:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

I used the following code at the MySQL prompt to change the variable from the 30s to 60s:

```
mysql> set global net_read_timeout = 60;
```

I check if the variable's value changed:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'net_read_timeout';
```

It has changed to 60s.

then I exit from MySQL again type mysql at the terminal (as root always in this case) and check again if MySQL has held net_read_timeout = 60 s. It held the value.

Now I exit MySQL again and at the linux terminal I type the following to import `B.sql` into `myDataBase`:

```
mysql myDataBase < B.sql
```

and I get this error message:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 41: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

It doesn't take more than a few seconds to get this error message, definitely not 30s. Nevertheless, I go back to check the value of net_read_time out.

I start MySQL as root and type:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'net_read_timeout';
```

I see that net_read_timeout is back to 30s.

I tried to go to MySQL configuration files to change this variable manually:

I use Ubuntu LTS 20.04 (server), and I find the configuration files in the following path:

```
/etc/mysql
```

which included the following files and directories:

```
conf.d  debian-start  debian.cnf  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback  mysql.cnf  mysql.conf.d
```

Searching all of these files, I couldn't find the net_read_timeout variable. Also, I have noticed there wasn't much inside these files. There are other suggested variables to change their values for resolving this problem, for example, connect_timeout, and they are not in those configuration files.

Some of the configuration file names are repeated in subfolders, and this is a question about which one is the configuration file that MySQL is using.

**Summary and the main problem**

The `net_read_timeout` is reset to the initial value upon the time out during the query.